# K3 surfaces as double covers of P2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

Consider a K3 surface given as the double branched cover over P^2, branched along a smooth sextic.  What is the ramification divisor in the K3 surface?

Answer (score 6):

The ramification divisor projects isomorphically to the plane sextic curve.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: and it has  self-intersection equal to  18